Force word splitting for fallback value in sh/bash
I want use complex command as fallback value, something like this, but do not treat ls -sh as single string.
"${@:-ls -sh}"


consider updating the question with a minimal, reproducible example; in this case a complete script (function?), a couple sample calls (with and without args), and the expected result; also, you've tagged the question with two different shells - bash and sh - if you're using a specific shell then update the tags (delete the one you're not using), or are you looking for a solution that works in both shells?

@markp-fuso "${@:-ls -sh}" is the whole script contents. I want it to exec passed arguments as a command or exec fallback command. Currently it's posix-shell oblivious, but I do not hesitate to force bash, so tagged both.

I'm surprised that your command doesn't get rejected. @ is not a spcecial variable, more akin to an array (but with special features), and I don't think that doing the :- stuff can be done at all. At best, i would call what you are doing undefined behaviour.

Try
[ -n "${@:+X}" ] || set -- ls -sh
"$@"


See How to check if a variable is set in Bash for an explanation of [ -n "${@:+X}" ].
set -- ls -sh sets the positional parameters so $1 has the value 'ls' and $2 has the value '-sh'.
The code uses only POSIX shell features so it doesn't require Bash.


If args are guaranteed to not contain whitespace you can just drop the quotes. Otherwise you'll just have to go the long way:
(( $# == 0 )) && arr=(ls -sh) || arr=("$@")
# Now use "${arr[@]}" instead of "$@"


@pjh D'Oh! I withdraw my comment.
